# Invalid Parameter Error using facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-debugger

I am passing "https://www.cnbc.com/2019/01/13/saudi-energy-minister-on-work-with-oil-producers-to-balance-market.html" as the url to facebook sharing debugger at the following link:

[Facebook Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/)

We can see all the results which facebook has scraped. If we scroll down there and see the entries listed under the URLs section, we see an entry named Scrape API. If we click that it opens the graph api explorer with fields filled automatically.

```
POST/v3.2/?scrape=true&id=https://www.cnbc.com/2019/01/13/saudi-energy-minister-on-work-with-oil-producers-to-balance-market.html
```

It was working before but it suddenly stopped working. The error I get is as seen below:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid parameter",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 1611008,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Object Missing a Required Value",
    "error_user_msg": "Object at URL 'https://www.cnbc.com/2019/01/13/saudi-energy-minister-on-work-with-oil-producers-to-balance-market.html' of type 'article' is invalid because a required property 'al:ios:url' of type 'appsite' was not provided.",
    "fbtrace_id": "Gb0BSdJyfGb"
  }
}
```

What i am trying to achieve here is to get the data which facebook scrapes from the url given to the debugger.

**EDIT 1:**

If you use the following url as test and do the post request as described above. It works and the result is as follows:

**Test URL:** `https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2019-01-13/asian-stocks-to-start-mixed-with-earnings-in-focus-markets-wrap?srnd=premium`

**RESULT:**

```
{
  "url": "https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2019-01-13/asian-stocks-to-start-mixed-with-earnings-in-focus-markets-wrap",
  "type": "article",
  "title": "Stocks Fall, Bonds Rise as China and Banks Weigh: Markets Wrap",
  "image": [
    {
      "url": "https://assets.bwbx.io/images/users/iqjWHBFdfxIU/iZv8.HNBZJtU/v0/1200x674.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "description": "U.S. stocks declined and Treasuries rose as weak Chinese trade data and troubling signals in bank earnings weighed on investor confidence. The dollar edged lower.",
  "site_name": "Bloomberg.com",
  "updated_time": "2019-01-14T14:38:37+0000",
  "id": "2214485868588392"
}
```

Can someone shed some light as why other urls are not working though they work in the debugger?

Comment: "get data"? that is a call to update/rescrape, not to get data. you are using POST, not GET. i am not sure if it is even possible to use the API for that, to be honest.

Comment: @luschn Yes.I agree.If you use GET, it will give you a few attributes but not all of it. If you do POST, it returns all attrs like image etc. I tried and it was working but suddenly i started getting this error. You can try it the way i explained through debugger